# What is the best way to add fragment in the Tabs android

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

My application had a bottom navigation bar which has 5 tabs.
So according to these tabs, I have 5 fragments
When I click on the tab, the fragment changed according to that tab.
I can switch fragment by using the method beginTransaction().replace... 
I dont want the fragment to be destroyed and recreated again each time I switch tabs, so my solution is sth like this

```
//I init 5 fragments
Fragment1 frag1 = new Fragment1();
Fragment2 frag2 = new Fragment2();
Fragment3 frag3 = new Fragment3();
Fragment4 frag4 = new Fragment4();
Fragment5 frag5 = new Fragment5();

//When I click on tab, for example tab1, I hide all fragments except tab1
//hide all fragments
getSupportFragmentManager()
                    .beginTransaction()
                    .hide(fragment1) //Fragment2, 3, 4, 5 as well
                    .commit();

//show fragment 1
getSupportFragmentManager()
                    .beginTransaction()
                    .show(fragment1)
                    .commit();
```

It works very well, but the problem is sometimes 2 fragments show at once time (I dont know why because I hide all fragments)
Any other way to achieve that? Switch fragment without destroying it and creating it again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `ViewPager` with `FragmentPagerAdapter` suits for you in this case.

Then use `ViewPager#setOffsetPageLimit(5)`. This will help you show/hide your fragments without recreating it again.

Follow this [tutorial](https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/ViewPager-with-FragmentPagerAdapter)

Let try it, then tell me if your problem is solved or not. ;)

Comment: it is called: `setOffscreenPageLimit()`

Comment: It delayed too much when I switched the tab. And the fragment kept recreated again (even when I used SmartFragmentStatePagerAdapter)

Comment: SmartFragmentStatePagerAdapter & FragmentStatePagerAdapter is useful when you have a lot of Fragments (Like bookreader app). Use FragmentPagerAdapter is enough. Please upload your code, so I can take a look

Comment: It works, I forgot to add setOffscreenPageLimit. Thank you very much. I am a beginner to android, how can you learn android. Any courses, pages or books that you recommend me

Comment: Udacity, codepath, stackoveflow Documentation are great resources.

Comment: Omg, I did not realize that stackoverflow has documentation. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

for adding fragment I make this code for my project, hope it will be help.

```
 public static void replaceFragment(Fragment fragment, FragmentManager fragmentManager) {
        String backStateName = fragment.getClass().getName();
        String fragmentTag = backStateName;


        Fragment currentFrag = fragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.frame_container);
        Log.e("Current Fragment", "" + currentFrag);

//        boolean fragmentPopped = fragmentManager.popBackStackImmediate(backStateName, 0);
        int countFrag = fragmentManager.getBackStackEntryCount();
        Log.e("Count", "" + countFrag);


        if (currentFrag != null && currentFrag.getClass().getName().equalsIgnoreCase(fragment.getClass().getName())) {
            return;
        }


        FragmentTransaction ft = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
//        if (!fragmentPopped) {

        ft.replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment);
        ft.addToBackStack(backStateName);
        ft.commit();
//        }

        currentFrag = fragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.frame_container);
        Log.e("Current Fragment", "" + currentFrag);


    }
```

hope this will be help you, and use this method in entire project for replacing fragment.

Answer (score 0):

you don't have to need to hide the fragment just replace the fragment like this method:

```
public void setFragment(Fragment fragmentWhichYouWantToShow) {

        fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
        ft = fm.beginTransaction();
        ft.replace(R.id.container, fragmentWhichYouWantToShow);
        ft.commit();
```

}

Comment: do i know the reason to downVote?

Comment: I don't know answer on your question, upvoted. The difference is in lifecycle. When you replace fragment A with B, A's view is destroyed. But when you hide fragment A and show B, A's view is not destroyed.

Comment: Yeah, the view is not destroyed because we just 'hide' it. Because nothing happened with the activity

Answer (score 0):

Try to make it in a singe transaction.

```
protected void showAsRootFragment(Fragment fragment, @NonNull String tag) {
    FragmentManager supportFragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();        
    FragmentTransaction transaction = supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    if (supportFragmentManager.getFragments() != null) {
        for (Fragment attachedFragment : supportFragmentManager.getFragments()) {
            if (attachedFragment != null && !tag.equals(attachedFragment.getTag())) {
                transaction.hide(attachedFragment);
                attachedFragment.setUserVisibleHint(false);
            }
        }
    }

    if (!fragment.isAdded()) {
        transaction.add(R.id.frame_container, fragment, tag);
        fragment.setUserVisibleHint(true);
    } else {
        transaction.show(fragment);
        fragment.setUserVisibleHint(true);
    }

    transaction.commit();
}
```