# android ram kept going up and up when i add value to the arraylist to add content into the listview

Tags: java, android, listview

I have a listview inside one of 3 fragments, located inside an activity.

The way my code works: A button inside the activity calls a function inside the pageAdapter. The adapter function then calls the function inside the fragment to add value and refresh the listview using notifyDataSetInvalidated();

My goal: When I pressed a button inside the activity, the pageAdapter function will add content to the listview. This content is then placed in the fragment.

My problem: Everything seem to work as I programmed it. However, when I look at the android profiler, this app seems to take up a lot of memory. Every time I click the button the ram/memory keeps increasing 1 mb. Additionally, every time I added a value the RAM increased anywhere from 40-100 mb and does not decrease.

Why does this happen? Is this normal? Is this a memory leak? How can I solve this issue? Is there a better way for me to reference the fragment?

here is the code for the MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements listFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener,list2Fragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener,list3Fragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener {


    private TabLayout tabLayout;

    private Button micBtn;

    private ImageButton camBtn;
    private TextView resultText;

    PagerAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



        // instantiate the textview and button
        resultText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.micText);
        // mic button
        micBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.micBtn);


        //toolbar
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);

        camBtn = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.menubar);
        camBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent Intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,CameraActivity.class);
                startActivity(Intent);
            }
        });
        // end of toolbar code

        // tablayout
        tabLayout = (TabLayout)findViewById(R.id.tablayout);
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("list2"));
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("list"));
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("list3"));
        tabLayout.setTabGravity(TabLayout.GRAVITY_FILL);

        final ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.mainviewpager);
        adapter = new PagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), tabLayout.getTabCount());

        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
        viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener( tabLayout));

        tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
                System.out.print("this is the "+tab.getPosition());
            }

            @Override
            public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }
        });
        // end of tablayout code

    }

    public void ontest(View v){
        adapter.addList();
    }


    public void onButtonClick(View v){
        if(v.getId() == R.id.micBtn){
            promptSpeechInput();
        }
    }

    public  void promptSpeechInput(){
        Intent i = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
        i.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL,RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
        i.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL, Locale.getDefault());
        i.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PROMPT,"say something");

        try {
            startActivityForResult(i, 100);
        }catch(ActivityNotFoundException a){
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"sorry your device does not support speech to text ",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

    public void onActivityResult(int request_code,int result_code,Intent i){
        super.onActivityResult(request_code,result_code,i);

        switch (request_code)
        {
            case 100: if(result_code == RESULT_OK && i != null){
                ArrayList<String> result = i.getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);
                resultText.setText(result.get(0));
            }
            break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri) {
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"4324",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }





}
```

here is the code for pageAdapter

```
public class PagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

    int mNoOfTabs;

    listFragment CF;

    public PagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, int NumberOfTabs){
        super(fm);
        this.mNoOfTabs = NumberOfTabs;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        switch (position){

            case 0:
                list2Fragment NF = new list2Fragment();
                return  NF;
            case 1:
                 CF = new listFragment();
                return  CF;
            case 2:
                list3Fragment TF = new list3Fragment();
                return  TF;
            default:
                return null;
        }

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mNoOfTabs;
    }

    public void addList(){
        CF.addlist();

    }

}
```

here is the code for the fragment

```
public class listFragment extends Fragment {
    // TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
    // the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
    private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
    private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";

    // TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
    private String mParam1;
    private String mParam2;

    private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;

    // array s
    int[] counter = {2,23,41,2,2};
    public ArrayList<String> mylist = new ArrayList<String>();

    listAdapter listAdapter;

    public listFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    /**
     * Use this factory method to create a new instance of
     * this fragment using the provided parameters.
     *
     * @param param1 Parameter 1.
     * @param param2 Parameter 2.
     * @return A new instance of fragment tab1.
     */
    // TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
    public static listFragment newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
        listFragment fragment = new listFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        mylist.add("hello");
        mylist.add("nice");
        mylist.add("cool");
        mylist.add("gaming");

        if (getArguments() != null) {
            mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
            mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
        }
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_list, container, false);
        ListView listView = (ListView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.listListView);

        listAdapter = new listAdapter();

        listView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
        return rootView;

    }

    public class listAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mylist.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {

            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            convertView = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.adapter_list,null);

            TextView textView = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView);

            textView.setText(mylist.get(position));
            return convertView;
        }
    }

    // TODO: Rename method, update argument and hook method into UI event
    public void onButtonPressed(Uri uri) {
        if (mListener != null) {
            mListener.onFragmentInteraction(uri);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        if (context instanceof OnFragmentInteractionListener) {
            mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) context;
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException(context.toString()
                    + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        mListener = null;
    }

    /**
     * This interface must be implemented by activities that contain this
     * fragment to allow an interaction in this fragment to be communicated
     * to the activity and potentially other fragments contained in that
     * activity.
     * <p>
     * See the Android Training lesson <a href=
     * "http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html"
     * >Communicating with Other Fragments</a> for more information.
     */
    public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
        // TODO: Update argument type and name
        void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri);
    }

    public OnFragmentInteractionListener getmListener() {
        return mListener;
    }

    public void addlist(){
        Toast.makeText(getContext(),"i am clicked",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        mylist.add("hello");
        listAdapter.notifyDataSetInvalidated();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**why is this happening? is it normal?**

It's normal. Consider this - every time you're adding something to your arraylist, your app needs to store that data somewhere. Since you're not writing your list to disk for persistent long term storage, it's stored in the RAM for the running instance of your program.

**is this a memory leak? how do i solve this problem?**

Normally, most IDE's give a warning whenever there's a potential memory leak. But in this case, whatever you add to your arraylist seems to be continually referenced later on - so if my understanding is correct, it's not a memory leak. That only occurs whenever you have an object that's no longer referenced, but cannot be collected by the garbage collector.

As for solving the issue with memory, you can always try a different approach. Like I hinted earlier, if your list is something that will persist through several runs, I'd recommend storing that output to an external list and calling it whenever you need it. Another option would be to remove objects from your arraylist if you no longer need them. It's really hard to say without understanding the full scope of what you need the list for.

**is there better way for the activity to communicate with the fragment?**

[What is the best way to add fragment in the Tabs android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45541667/what-is-the-best-way-to-add-fragment-in-the-tabs-android)

This link might have some of what you're looking for, if you wanted alternative options

Comment: thank you for the clearance man, i think i am starting to get it. i did the exact same thing for the iphone. but it does not increase the RAM, so i it freaking me out when i see this happening when i use android.